# Given the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$, find the probability density function of $Z = XY$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, density-function, marginal-distribution

The joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $f(x,y) = xe^{-x(y+1)}$, $x > 0, y > 0$.

(a) Find the conditional density of $X$, given $Y = y$, and that
of $Y$, given $X = x$.

(b) Find the density function of $Z = XY$.

**MY SOLUTION**

In the first place, we should determine the marginal distributions:
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y = \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x(y+1)}\mathrm{d}y = xe^{-x}
\end{align*}

where $x > 0$. Analogously, we have
\begin{align*}
f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x(y+1)}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{(y+1)^{2}}
\end{align*}

where $y > 0 $.

(a) Based on the previous results, it comes

\begin{cases}
f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \displaystyle\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)} = x(y+1)^{2}e^{-x(y+1)}\\\\
f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \displaystyle\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)} = e^{-xy}
\end{cases}

(b) Finally, we have
\begin{align*}
F_{Z}(z) & = \textbf{P}(XY \leq z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{z/x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{z/x}xe^{-x(y+1)}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-x} - e^{-x-z})\mathrm{d}x = 1 - e^{-z} \Rightarrow f_{Z}(z) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(1-e^{-z}) = e^{-z}
\end{align*}

where $z > 0$.

Comment: Hmmm, it appears that your integral for $f_X(x)$ may not be correct. I got $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$. My answers for the other parts are the same as yours. We differ only in the expression for $f_X(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint density $f(x,y)$ factors in the following ways:

$$f(x,y)=xe^{-xy}\mathbf1_{y>0}\,e^{-x}\mathbf1_{x>0}\tag{1}$$

$$f(x,y)=(1+y)^2xe^{-(1+y)x}\mathbf1_{x>0}\,\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}\mathbf1_{y>0}\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ it follows that the conditional density of $Y\mid X$ is

$$f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)=xe^{-xy}\mathbf1_{y>0}$$

, and the marginal density of $X$ is $$f_X(x)=e^{-x}\mathbf1_{x>0}$$

From $(2)$, your answer for the conditional and marginal densities is correct.

So your answer for $f_X(x)$, though seemingly okay as it integrates to unity, is not correct. As a result, $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$ (the variable is $y$ here because it is a function of $y$ for a given $x$, not $(x,y)$ as you have written) is also out of line. The rest looks okay.

Comment: In the first place, thank you very much for the contribution. As to the notation of conditional probability, I think the most common way to denote it is $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$.

Comment: That is the notation used in books, to emphasize the "given $x$" part.

Comment: (+1) A minor quibble: the notation $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ is common, one could even argue it is preferable to $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$.